# Why do we persist in saying the crucifixion was on Friday?

Tags: chronology, sabbath, crucifixion

There are [persuasive arguments](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=crucifixion%20on%20Friday%3F) for the crucifixion **not** being on a Friday.  I guess the Friday hypothesis is based on the reference to it [being before **a** Sabbath](https://biblehub.com/john/19-31.htm), and not knowing some of the details of those arguments.

But that would imply that the gospel writers were numerically challenged—unable to recognize that Friday night and Saturday night are only two nights.  Or liars who were stupid enough to think that nobody would notice this.  Of course, I don’t think either of those implications are true, which is why **I am totally puzzled that the Good Friday hypothesis is consistently treated as truth by almost everyone.**  (Including people who are clearly ***not*** stupid.)

So why is that hypothesis/tradition so prevalent?

Comment: You might want to tone down  your adjectives describing gospel writers as liars and stupid unless readers agree with you. The question is a good one but the tone is inflammatory - subtly putting down those who don't see it your way. See [code of conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct) guidelines

Comment: I did not describe them as such.  I said the Good Friday idea would imply that,  Perhaps my edit would make that more obvious.

Comment: @DanFefferman please don't forget to Vote to Close questions that don't follow the site scope. This is not a question about any particular text, and may well be a duplicate among dozens of similar questions about when exactly the Easter events happened. New users need your help and guidance to use the site well.

Comment: It may be off-topic as "not about any particular text" but it ISN'T a duplicate.  It asks why people believe what to me is obviously false.  I did not ask when the crucifixion occurred.

Comment: Fair enough - I'd have thought that many of the answers out there gave fairly solid substantiations of the reasons why people take different stances on the texts, so I'm not really sure what else you're hoping for?

Comment: Well, there were too many to read them all, but all the ones I read said what I already believe—that it was not on a Friday.  I didn't read any that said it was Friday nor said why people continue to say it was.

Comment: As much as I agree with the idea behind your question, I agree that the question itself is inappropriate for this site as it is currently worded. This site is intended for examining the translation or intended meaning of a specific scripture, and this question doesn't even provide a scripture. Christianity.SE would perhaps be more appropriate, but again questions on that site also have strict requirements. The question must indicate which denomination's viewpoint you want to know about. (E.g. "was Jesus the son of God?" (bad) versus "Why don't Jehovah's Witnesses believe Jesus was …?" (good).)

Comment: This kind of seems like ["stump-the-chump"](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394/should-we-avoid-stump-the-chumps-questions) as written. (I could be wrong, though).

Comment: The answer to this involves the habit of Bible writers to use "inclusive time reckoning" which should be a separate question.  When understood this, the "problem" evaporates.  Perhaps you should ask about why only two nights can be described as three days?  Or something similar.  However, there are many questions about that on this site.

Comment: You might be able to get it re-opened if you did a text analysis yourself. The fact that the Pharisees wanted the body off the cross before sundown when the Sabbath starts (Jn 19:31) is somewhat of a shoe-in. But, I'm always intrigued by good evidence and arguments of new ideas, and I think others would love a good discussion. To do that, you would need 1. to focus on specific text(s) telling that part of the narrative, 2. with your arguments to raise the discussion, and 3. not ask about "why people believe" something because that is a statistical question of social choice, not hermeneutics.

Answer (score 1):

> Now it was the day of Preparation, and the next day was to be a special Sabbath. Because the Jewish leaders did not want the bodies left on the crosses during the Sabbath, they asked Pilate to have the legs broken and the bodies taken down. 32 The soldiers therefore came and broke the legs of the first man who had been crucified with Jesus, and then those of the other. 33 But when they came to Jesus and found that he was already dead, they did not break his legs. 34 Instead, one of the soldiers pierced Jesus’ side with a spear, bringing a sudden flow of blood and water. 35 The man who saw it has given testimony, and his testimony is true. He knows that he tells the truth, and he testifies so that you also may believe. 36 These things happened so that the scripture would be fulfilled: “Not one of his bones will be broken,” 37 and, as another scripture says, “They will look on the one they have pierced.”
> (John 19)

This says Christ died the day before the Sabbath

> From noon until three in the afternoon darkness came over all the land. 46 About three in the afternoon Jesus cried out in a loud voice, “Eli, Eli, lema sabachthani?” (which means “My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?”).
>
> 47 When some of those standing there heard this, they said, “He’s calling Elijah.”
>
> 48 Immediately one of them ran and got a sponge. He filled it with wine vinegar, put it on a staff, and offered it to Jesus to drink. 49 The rest said, “Now leave him alone. Let’s see if Elijah comes to save him.”

(Matthew 27)

This says that he died at approximately three in the after noon. We know that a Jewish day began at sunset, and began at sunrise. We know no one could tell time at night. This shows that it couldn’t habe been much after sunset. We know that sunset was at the twelfth hour (Jewish time) and 6PM (Roman time). We know that the third hour (Jewish time) is equivalent to 9AM (Roman time). This means, whether we measure by Jewish or Roman time, it was in Friday.

As for the convincing arguments, they are only convincing to someone who doesn’t know how the Jewish calendar works.

I saw one referencing how years are different. That is true, but that means nothing if one doesn’t know why. Our years are measured by the sun. Their years are measured by the moon. Neither are measured by days.

I saw one that claimed feasts can’t fall on Sabbath in the modern Jewish calendar. That is simply false, they can and do. They prepare the Passover the day before. It is important to note, the Passover is on Sabbath often.

Comment: So, you are saying Jesus can't tell the difference between two and three?  Or the gospel writers couldn't?  I’m quite familiar with how lunar calendars work and if you had read the cited items, you’d know that they weren’t written by clueless people.  And I’ve read all those scriptures many times.

Comment: You say "*This says Christ died the day before the Sabbath*", but it doesn't.  It says "*the next day was to be **a** special Sabbath*", not "**the**" Sabbath. The 15th of the month was the first day of Passover, a High Sabbath, not necessarily the weekly sabbath. And some versions translate Matthew 28:1 as "*After the sabbaths*" (plural). If the Crucifixion were on a Wednesday afternoon, that would also match the "*three days and three nights*" that Jesus said he would be buried (Mathew and Luke).

Comment: Welcome to BHse, TacoBlayno ;-) Please don't be put off by downvotes. So far you've got one up (by me) and one down. Your answer was useful, whether one agrees with it or not.

Comment: @RayButterworth, I said no such thing.  I even put 'a' in bold, not "the."  And the question in the title AND in bold is fairly clear.

Comment: It's useful, but it does NOT answer the question.  It says all the cited arguments are wrong and continues to insist that Jesus was only in the grave two nights or fewer.

Comment: @WGroleau, "*said no such thing*". True. My comment is about this answer, not about your question.

Comment: Sabbath is always Saturday, high Sabbath is to say that start of the Passover was especially important because it was on Sabbath. I edited my post, because I mistakeningly said Passover is a week long, but that is actually the holiday that always follows Passover. https://penelope.uchicago.edu/~grout/encyclopaedia_romana/calendar/jesus.html